# How to find the length of a json.Unmarshalled() object in GoLang?

Tags: go, marshalling, unmarshalling

["contexts"]I have this GoLang code:

```
1:      unmarshalledBody := make(map[string]interface{})
2:      err = json.Unmarshal(someData, &unmarshalledBody)
3:      fmt.Println(unmarshalledBody["some-key"])
4:      fmt.Println(len(unmarshalledBody["some-key"]))
```

Line #3 causes this output:

```
[map[A:R B:T C:V] map[A:S B:U C:W]]
```

Line #4 causes this error:

```
invalid argument unmarshalledBody (type interface {}) for len
```

So how can I find out the length the the unmarshalled object?

Comment: It looks like your output doesn't match the code you've given. For example the output of the maps you gave is an array, but the code indicates only one map.

Comment: Corrected the question.

Comment: Do a type assertion on the value. eg: `s, ok := unmarshalledBody["some-key"].(whatever-type-it-is)`.

Answer (score 0):

func len(v Type) int

The len built-in function returns the length of v, according to its type:

```
Array: the number of elements in v.
Pointer to array: the number of elements in *v (even if v is nil).
Slice, or map: the number of elements in v; if v is nil, len(v) is zero.
String: the number of bytes in v.
Channel: the number of elements queued (unread) in the channel buffer;
     if v is nil, len(v) is zero.
```

https://golang.org/src/builtin/builtin.go?s=5935:5955#L148

suggestion:

```
val, ok := unmarshalledBody["some-key"].(type)
```